# Prestashop megamenu

Tags: menu, navigation, prestashop

I purchased a prestashop template but struggling to get the navigation drop down how i need it, i've asked there support and they don't seem to understand hopefully someone here will be able to help.

My nav has a drop down which then lists capping, wipers, dampers, boards etc but under each of these is Roland, Mimaki, Mutoh and Epson. I want to hide roland, mimaki, mutoh and epson from the drop down as its overcrowding the menu.

I tried this from a tutorial but either it dont work or I'm putting it in the wrong place of the code:

```
if ($category['level_depth'] < 4 
          && isset($category['children']) 
          && !empty($category['children']))
```

http://nemops.com/prestashop-top-menu-limit-subcategories/#.WNOfifmLSUk

Hopefully someone can help

Comment: Does any have any ideas :(

Comment: We actually need more to complete your request. Can you just do something like a "var_dump" of the array and expose us the whole loop ?

Answer (score 0):

The theme you bought probably has a separate module for the drop-down menu.
Go to the Back End of your Prestashop Framework, select 'Module & Services.' Search for the module and see if there something that can be done.

Answer (score 0):

GO to the BackOffice of your store, select Modules & Services, then click "Installed Modules" then fin your MegaMenu, I´m using megamenu in my page and there is an option "Build subMenu" There you have to add cols and row to build your menu.